# Позиционирование блоков div на странице

Tags: css, html

подскажите пожалуйста, не могу разобраться с проблемой. Есть страница, добавляю на неё три блока и прописываю им свойства в css:

```css
.div_1 {
 position: absolute;
 background: #000;
 height: 66px;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0%;
 right: 0%;
 top: 0%;
 bottom: 0%;
 z-index: 2;
}
.div_2 {
 position: absolute;
 background: #29313C;
 height: 100%;
 width: 80px;
 left: 0%;
 right: 0%;
 top: 0%;
 bottom: 0%;
 z-index: 1;
}

.div_3 {
 position: absolute;
 background: #f2f2f2;
 height: 92.85%;
 width: 95.5%;
 left: 80px;
 right: 0%;
 top: 66px;
 bottom: 0%;
 z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="div_1"></div>
  <div class="div_2"></div>
  <div class="div_3"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

И получается так, что при сжатии окна браузера div_3 у меня выходит за размеры div_1. Подскажите в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: а вы код здесь пробовали выполнить? Что-то не очень понял что куда выходит

Comment: А у вас z-index должен быть именно таким?
div_1 - 2
div_2 - 1
div_3 - 1

Comment: z-index я добавил только из за тени, чтобы тень верхнего блока заходила на нижний. В рабочем варианте должна быть верхняя панель, которая занимает всё пространство в ширину и уменьшается вместе с браузером, боковая, тоже самое но в длину, а третий блок чтобы заполнял всё, что осталось. Но при сжатии браузера третий блок выходит за пределы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного видоизменил css третего блока, думаю это то, что Вам нужно.

```css
.div_1 {
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  height: 66px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.div_2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: #29313C;
  height: 100%;
  width: 80px;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.div_3 {
  position: absolute;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  height: 100% - 66px;
  width: 100% - 80px;
  left: 80px;
  right: 0%;
  top: 66px;
  bottom: 0%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="div_1"></div>
<div class="div_2"></div>
<div class="div_3"></div>
```

Comment: И правда работает) спасибо большое